# How to authenticate guest user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel5.4 i have one call page which is accessable by authenticated users. But in my application i have a feature like "invite user". If we invite user who are not part of my application they can also join in call page. But this type of users are not stored in users table. I will store in another table like guestusers. When ever snding the invitation i will add that into this table along with unique token. i will send a link along with this token to guest user. But how to authenticate this type of users in laravel?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: You could use Middleware?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to create a specific "guest user" record in your database and then create a middleware that queries your guest_users table. If the user is in that table then you can use `Auth::loginUsingId($user_id, true);` where `$user_id` equals your special guest user record. The bool flag sets "remember me" in a session cookie. Does that make sense?